# How do you find the min/max values of $Arg(z)$ for {$z:|z-(4+3i)|=2$}?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, absolute-value, angle

How do you find the min/max values of $Arg(z)$ for {$z:|z-(4+3i)|=2$}?

I have drawn a diagram with a circle centre $(4+3i)$ and radius = $2$. I think to find the min/max values of $Arg(z)$ I need to find the points of tangency? I don't understand how to do it only with the diagram and any hints would be much appreciated!

The min possible value of $|z|$ is $3$, and max value of $|z|$ is $7$.

Also, I am on a chapter has more simple questions like this, so I'm looking for a not too complicated way of solving this :)

Comment: Hint: find the tangents to the circle from the origin.

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data I do not understand how to do this - I tried substituting y=mx into the cartesian equation, but I am not getting the correct answer..

Comment: That's not going to work, since you can't solve for both $m$ and $x$ with just one quadratic. You basically have two options: (i) Use Trignometry, or (ii) use $$S S_1=T^2$$ and find the pair of lines, which you can then isolate. Trignometry is much easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the greatest value of $\arg z$ achieved on a circle in $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205914/find-the-greatest-value-of-arg-z-achieved-on-a-circle-in-mathbbc)

Answer (score 2):

In the following picture, the points you require are $C$ and $D$, since any point above the line $AC$ (and hence, with slope more than that of $AC$) and below the line $AD$ (and hence, with slope less than that of $AD$) will not lie on the circle. Since, the whole circle is in the first quadrant, the slope of the line joining a point $D$ on the circle and the origin is same as $\tan\theta$ where $\theta$ is the argument of the complex number $D(x,y):=x+\iota y$.

*According to the problem, the center of the circle is $B(4,3)$ and radius is $BD=BC=2$*

Now, what you need is $\angle DAE$ and $\angle CAE$ ($BE \perp AE$) $$\begin{aligned} \angle DAE &= \angle BAE - \angle BAD \\ & = \sin^{-1}\dfrac{BE}{BA} - \sin^{-1} \dfrac{DB}{BA}\\ & = \sin^{-1} \dfrac35-\sin^{-1} \dfrac25 \ (\because BA = \sqrt{4^2+3^2}=5) \\ &=(0.6435 - 0.4115)\text{rad}=0.232\text{ rad}\\ \text{and } \ \angle CAE &=\angle BAE+\angle CAB \\&= \sin^{-1}\dfrac{BE}{BA} +\sin^{-1} \dfrac{CB}{BA}\\&=\sin^{-1} \dfrac35+\sin^{-1} \dfrac25\\ &=(0.6435 +0.4115)\text{rad}=1.055\text{ rad}\end{aligned}$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=mx$ be the equation of a line tangent to the circle $(x-4)^2 + (y-3)^2 =4$. Then substituting the first into the second, we get

$$
\begin{align}
(x-4)^2 + (mx-3)^2 &= 4 \\
(m^2 + 1) \, x^2 - (6m+8) \, x +21 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Since the line is tangent to the circle, the discriminant of the above must be zero.

$$
\begin{align}
(6m+8)^2 - 4 (m^2 + 1)(21) &= 0 \\
12m^2 - 24m + 5 &= 0 \\
m &= \frac{6 \pm \sqrt{21}}{6}
\end{align}
$$

Finally, we have $\tan \theta = m$, so

$$\theta_1 = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{6 - \sqrt{21}}{6} \right) = 0.232$$

and

$$\theta_2 = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{6 + \sqrt{21}}{6} \right) = 1.055$$